# Sticky on a page without scroll

Tags: html, css, sass

How can a page without scroll have an element that sticks to the top of a div that has `overflow-y: scroll`?

Example:
[image]

You can see the div that has a table have overflow-y: scroll. Now I want to make the table header sticky to the top of the parent div. Is this even possible? Also have in mind that the div may have overflow-x as well.

Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: See: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/

Comment: Unfortunately that example doesn't work if the page doesn't have scrollbar. It needs to hit the viewport and in my case that will not happen. Only the table div have scroll, not the page itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position: sticky; top: 0;
```

This will help out to get the table header fixed inside the overflow container. For example:

```
`<div class="table-container" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="table-header style="position: sticky; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="table-body"></div>
</div>
`
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `position: sticky` needs the element to hit the viewport and in this case this will not happen because the page itself does not have scrollbar. Only the table div have scroll

Comment: Was this not the desired outcome? https://codepen.io/jungmoney/pen/MWYGyOR

Comment: Yes my bad. I did not accomplish the result you did with the codepen so that's why I said that. Thanks for your help mate :D